# Highstock/Highcharts - yAxis Label top

Tags: highcharts

Using Highstock or Highcharts, I want my yAxis label on the top. What I don't want, is a varying margin between the left border of the chart and the beginning of the grid lines.

If you take a look at the following fiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/title-offset/)

Relevant part is:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        align: 'high',
        offset: 0,
        text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
        rotation: 0,
        y: -10
    }
}
```

This is almost correct, but the offset margin is taken from the label width. If I set `offset: -41` instead, it looks exactly right. The problem is, that the `-41` is due to the rendered length of the text. If I change the text to something of a different length, the label is positioned wrongly again.

Is there any possibility to make sure, that the positions are always "correct" in my above definition of correct, regardless of the text length?

Screenshot, left part is wrong, right part is correct:

[image: Display Difference]

Comment: I think that you can use text-anchor property to style your title, here you can get some more info about text-anchor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

and here you can find live example with this option: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljwp7694/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Make that an answer and you get the acceptance mark. I got the missing parameters from your fiddle.

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Please remove "highstock" word, highstock needs a different solution for this issue, having this word will bring here people looking for a highstock solution on any search engine. Example and code provided are for Highchart only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use text-anchor property to style your title. Here you can find more information about text-anchor property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

```
  title: {
    align: 'high',
    text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
    style: {
      'text-anchor': 'start'
    },
    rotation: 0,
    y: -10,
    x: -25
  },
```

I think that you need to use chart.marginLeft parameter as well. It will give you a chance to set specific left margin for your chart. Here you can find information about it.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginLeft

You may also use xAxis.labels.reserveSpace parameter to turn off reserving space for labels: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.reserveSpace

Here you can find live example how your chart can work with this options:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ljwp7694/

Kind regards,

Comment: It wasn't the `text-anchor` alone, that helped. It was a combination of `chart:{marginLeft: 50}`, `labels: {reserveSpace: false}` together with the `title` options that did the trick.

Comment: Of course, marginLeft gives you a chance to set specific distance for your chart to start, reserveSpace option helped here as well. I will update my answer with this information.