# Left-align y-axis title with labels in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts, I'd like to put the y-axis title at the top and have it left-aligned with the y-axis labels.

I've tried this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    yAxis: {
        ...
        title: {
            align: 'high',
            text: 'Y-axis title',
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10,

            //To left-align title with labels
            textAlign: 'left', //This is undocumented, but appears to work
            margin: 0
        }
    }
})
```

However, I get an excessive left margin which seems to be proportional to the length of the y-axis title.

[image: Highcharts left-align y-axis title]
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eeuay58/1)

It looks like the margin calculation doesn't take into account the `textAlign: 'left'` setting.

UPDATE: I should say that my current "solution" is to set a margin with `chart.marginLeft` but that's not ideal because it's fixed. The left margin should be just big enough to accommodate the axis labels (however big they might be).

How can I left-align the y-axis title with the labels and have a reasonable left margin?

Comment: I think that here you can find a solution for your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327772/highstock-yaxis-label-top?noredirect=1#comment64072862_38327772

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz. I should have said in my question (and have now) that I'd rather not use `marginLeft` because it's a fixed value that won't adjust to the size of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `marginLeft` (yes, you read that correctly), but based on the **length of your axis label**, to provide the needed flexibility.

What I did here is set your chart options to a variable called `chartOptions`. I then calculated the length (number of characters) of the axis title, set the `marginLeft` property based on that value, and then drew the chart with the amended chart options.

```
chartOptions.chart.marginLeft = chartOptions.yAxis.title.text.length;
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/6eeuay58/9/

I tested it with different numbers by increasing some of your data points.

Please let me know if this is useful and helpful for you.